# Joblib ImportError. Tries to load a library I think it shouldn't be looking for in the first place

Tags: python, python-2.7, joblib

I am saving an object with `joblib.dump()`. When I try to open it using another Python instance (but same version), joblib complains it can't load a particular module:

```
ImportError: No module named some_module
```

Now, this module `some_module` is indeed not available in that Python instance.
The point is, however, that the object I was trying to load does not need that module at all.

So my question is, why does joblib think it needs this package?

Does it somehow include all module that were active at the time of dumping?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Joblib uses `pickle`. The `pickle` can store any arbitrary Python object to disk and restore it into another process afterwards. But if that Python object is, or contains, an instance of a class that is defined in the code that does the dump, then that class definition needs to be available in the code that does the load.

And if that class is defined in a library that was *imported by* the code that does the dump, then it also needs to import that library at load time. You don't have to do the import: `pickle` will do that for you. But it must be available for import.

I understand that you don't think that the object you are trying to load needs the class. But `pickle` does think that.

Comment: Thanks!

"But if that Python object is, or contains, an instance of a class that is defined in the code that does the dump, then that class definition needs to be available in the code that does the load.".  

Indeed. That is what I expected.  

"And if that class is defined in a library that was imported by the code that does the dump, then it also needs to import that library at load time."  

OK, I think that is what is getting me.

Comment: So, the next question is... how can I avoid this ;-) I guess I can unload the module before dumping?

Comment: I'd say you need to create a stripped-down version of the object before dumping it, that leaves out external references that the loading code won't be able to supply. Start by finding out where the reference to some_module is and eliminating that. Or provide a stub class in the loading code that satisfies the references but does nothing.

Comment: Well, the point is, the object I am dumping does not have any references to some_module. So, I can't strip it down with respect to that.

Comment: Maybe you think it doesn't, but `pickle` does. The reference may be indirect, in other words, it is a module that is imported by something your code imports. Create an empty file in the local directory called some_module.py and see which of your imports fails as a result.

Comment: I am sorry, but now I am really confused... ;-) My _code_ certainly needs this some_module. So if I leave it out, the entire script certainly  will not run. However, I am fairly sure this _object_ I am saving does not require the module. So, I can take out this dratted module, for now, and everything works just fine indeed. However, in the end I do need it. Or am I not getting you right?

Comment: I think it must be `joblib` that is doing this, not `pickle`. I don't know if the structure of your code will permit this suggestion. Separate out the dump into a one-function module that doesn't have `some_module` in its namespace: it imports only `joblib` and whatever else it must have. Pass the object to be dumped into that function and dump it from there. That way, `joblib.dump()` can't try and second-guess you because it won't be able to see `some_module`.